# Is it possible to include additional information on the x-axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following Matplotlib plot[image]

and I would like to know if it is possible to include additional information on the x-axis in Matplotlib as the red dates that I included at the very beginning and the very end of the plot.

In my current version, these red dates are not in the plot. I use the following current code for creating the plot:

```
                        plt.title('Test Forecast (Best)')
                        plt.plot(forecast, zorder=1)
                        plt.plot(actual, zorder=0)
                        plt.xlabel('Timeslot')
                        plt.ylabel('Load')
                        plt.legend(['forecast', 'actual'], loc='upper left')
                        filename = folderPath + "\Forecast_Test_Best.png"
                        plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
                        plt.show()
```

**Update**: I tried to include the suggestion from an answer an I have this code:

```
                    plt.title('Test Forecast (Best)')
                    plt.plot(forecast, zorder=1)
                    plt.plot(actual, zorder=0)
                    plt.xlabel('Timeslot')
                    plt.ylabel('Load')
                    plt.legend(['forecast', 'actual'], loc='upper left')

                    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                    ax.plot(np.arange(40))
                        
                    # the x coords of this transformation are data, and the y coord are axes
                    trans = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
                        
                    ax.text(0, -0.07, 'LHS annotate', transform=trans, va='top', ha='center', color='r')
                        
                    plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
                    plt.show()
```

But now I get 2 plots: The original post without the annotation and one new plot with just a linear function (that I don't want to plot and I don't know where it comes from) with the annotation. What I want is to have the annoation in my figure.

Comment: `plot.axvspan(20, 40, color="red", alpha=0.3)` will color the graph in that region

Comment: @whitespace: Thanks for your comment. As written in my question, I would like to add additional information into the plot (and not only color the graph in that region). Do you know, if something like this is possible using Matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but perhaps the most useful is to learn a little bit about the transform stack:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(40))

# the x coords of this transformation are data, and the y coord are axes
trans = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)

ax.text(0, -0.07, 'LHS annotate', transform=trans, va='top', ha='center', color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that here we have specified the transform in data for x, and in axes-relative units for y.

One might complain that the fudge-factor of 0.07 is not very good, so we could apply an offset transform in physical units:

```
trans += mtransforms.ScaledTranslation(0, -20/72, fig.dpi_scale_trans)

ax.text(0, -0.0, 'LHS annotate', transform=trans, va='top', ha='center', color='r')
```

where the offset is now in points:

[image]

For more about transforms, see: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#using-offset-transforms-to-create-a-shadow-effect

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jody. I tried to include your approach to my case but it did not really work as intended (see my Update on the question).

Comment: You have to adapt the code to your situation.  In particular replace `ax.plot(np.arange(40))` by `ax.plot(yourX, yourY)`, whatever those are.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jody for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer.